# Select xarray/pandas index based on specific months

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, python-xarray

I have an xarray DataArray that I want to select the months April, May, June (similar to time.season=='JJA') for an entire time series.

Its structured like:

```
<xarray.DataArray 't2m' (time: 492, latitude: 81, longitude: 141)>
```

I have been previously selecting JJA by:

```
seasonal_data =temp_data.sel(time=temp_data['time.season']=='JJA')
```

I would like to do the same thing but with the months 'AMJ' instead. I can add any details that I might be missing.

Thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The easiest way to select custom months is to use boolean masks, e.g.,

```
def is_amj(month):
    return (month >= 4) & (month <= 6)

seasonal_data = temp_data.sel(time=is_amj(temp_data['time.month']))
```

Note that you need to use the bitwise operators like `&` or `|` because Python's built-ins `and` and `or` don't work on vectors. Also, you need the parentheses because bitwise operators have higher precedence than comparisons.

Comment: I had been trying to do this, but kept getting errors. This method worked super well. I assume that is how the time.season=='JJA' works in the underlying code?

Comment: Take a look for yourself:
https://github.com/pydata/xarray/blob/90c854fd0ad20a35935319eb5b45a827d3269e81/xarray/core/dataset.py#L69-L73

We actually use a trick with integer division modulo 4, which is probably slightly faster but also less clear (and less generalizable).

Comment: Hi @shoyer, Thanks for the example above. Its helped a lot. Additionally, I was wondering how do one can select, lets say, the Dec month from the previous year and a few months from the current year together. I tried the below function, but that gives an an empty array. (`def is_djfma(month): return (month >= 12) & (month <= 4)`) Do you have any quick suggestion for this? Thanks, Arindan.