# Time Series Chart: Groupby seasons (or specfic months) for multiple years in xarray

Tags: python, numpy, time-series, netcdf, python-xarray

Thank you for taking interest in my question.

I am hoping to do plot a temperature time series chart specifically between the months January to August from 1981-1999.

Below are my codes and attempts:

```
temperature = xr.open_dataarray('temperature.nc')

temp = temperature.sel(latitude=slice(34.5,30), longitude=slice(73,78.5))

templatlonmean = temp.mean(dim=['latitude','longitude'])-273.15

tempgraph1 = templatlonmean.sel(time=slice('1981','1999'))
```

The above commands read in fine without any errors.

Below are my attempts to divide the months into seasons:

1st Attempt

```
tempseason1 = tempgraph1.groupby("time.season").mean("time")

#Plotting Graph Command
myfig, myax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14,8))

timeyears = np.unique(tempgraph1["time.season"])
tempseason1.plot.line('b-', color='red', linestyle='--',linewidth=4, label='1981-1999 Mean')
```

I got this error:
"*Plotting requires coordinates to be numeric, boolean, or dates of type numpy.datetime64, datetime.datetime, cftime.datetime or pandas.Interval. Received data of type object instead.*"

I tried this as my second attempt (retrieved from this post [Select xarray/pandas index based on specific months](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40272222/select-xarray-pandas-index-based-on-specific-months))
However, I wasn't sure how can I plot a graph with this, so I tried the following:

```
def is_amj(month):
    return (month >= 4) & (month <= 6)

temp_seasonal = tempgraph1.sel(time=is_amj(tempgraph1['time.month']))

#Plotting Graph Command
timeyears = np.unique(tempgraph1["time.season"])
temp_seasonal.plot.line('b-', color='red', linestyle='--',linewidth=4, label='1981-1999 Mean')
```

And it caused no error but the graph was not ideal
[image: graph]

So I moved on to my 3rd attempt (from here http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/examples/monthly-means.html):

```
month_length = tempmean.time.dt.days_in_month

weights = month_length.groupby('time.season') / month_length.groupby('time.season').sum()


np.testing.assert_allclose(weights.groupby('time.season').sum().values, np.ones(4))


ds_weighted = (tempmean * weights).groupby('time.season').sum(dim='time')


ds_unweighted = tempmean.groupby('time.season').mean('time')


#Plot Commands
timeyears = np.unique(tempgraph1["time.season"])
ds_unweighted.plot.line('b-', color='red', linestyle='--',linewidth=4, label='1981-1999 Mean')
```

Still I got the same error as the 1st attempt:
"*Plotting requires coordinates to be numeric, boolean, or dates of type numpy.datetime64, datetime.datetime, cftime.datetime or pandas.Interval. Received data of type object instead*."

As I this command was used to plot weather maps rather than time series chart, however I believed the groupby process would be similar or the same even, thats's why I used it.

However, as I am relatively new in coding, please excuse any syntax errors and that I am not able to spot any obvious ways to go about this.

Therefore, I am wondering if you could suggest any other ways to plot specific monthly datas for xarray or if there's any adjustment I need to make for the commands I have attempted.

I greatly appreciate your generous help.
Please let me know if you need any more further information, I will respond as soon as possible.
Thank you!

Comment: You have to do a type casting of the coordinates. My suggestion is that you should receive coordinates as numpy arrays and use the `astype` function. Afterwards overwrite the coordinates again.

Answer (score 0):

About your issues 1. and 3., the *object* is the seasons of grouping.
You can visualize that by doing:

```
tempseason1 = tempgraph1.groupby("time.season").mean("time")
print(tempseason1.coords)
```

You should see something like:

```
Coordinates:
  * lon      (lon) float32 ...
  * lat      (lat) float32 ...
  * season   (season) object 'DJF' 'JJA' 'MAM' 'SON'
```

Notice the type *object* of season dimension.

I think you should use `resample` instead of `groupby` here.
Resample is basically a groupby to upsample or downsample time series.
It would look like:

```
tempseason1 = tempgraph1.resample(time="Q").mean("time")
```

The argument "Q" is a pandas offset for quarterly frequency, see there for [details](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#resampling).

I don't know much about plotting though.